# Does String Literal Slice Usage with String references is Valid?

Tags: string, rust, clion

I have the following code block and it works as intended with no problem:

```
fn literal_taker(literals_slice: &[&str]){
    println!("{:?}",literals_slice);
}

fn string_taker(string_value: String){
    literal_taker(&[&string_value]);
}

fn main() {
    let string_value = String::from("Hello");
    string_taker(string_value);
}
```

Here, I pass the reference of `String` as a slice and it is compiling with no error and no clippy issue.

But the problem is, It is shown as warning in Clion Rust plugin:

[image]

Is it a bug of an plugin or am I doing something bad practice in Rust?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eac74822ce586d988761b326b7bf836b)

> [CLion Rust Plugin](https://intellij-rust.github.io/2018/09/26/changelog-83.html) Version: 0.2.0.2106-182

Comment: If I'm not wrong, this IDE has its own code validator. I guess that they did a mistake in it.

Comment: Did you really intend to move the `String` just to print it out once?

Comment: No it is just MCVE. Real code logic is different than println!

Comment: This error is emitted by your IDE, not by the compiler itself. You should compile your program to check if the **compiler** can do it, the IDE just guides you.

Comment: So, if we all sure about that this is a mistake of IDE and implementing such like this code is legit and elegant enough, Then I am closing it as off topic?

Comment: @AkinerAlkan, it isn't off-topic. It is a valid question, with answer that it is a CLion Rust Plugin issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code does compile as written, as the playground clearly demonstrates. Therefore it is a bug in the IDEA Rust Plugin.

Unlike most other Rust plugins that use the [Rust Language Server](https://github.com/rust-lang/rls), which uses code from the compiler, and therefore generally provides diagnostics consistent with what the compiler will, IntelliJ IDEA has its own validator, which might get things wrong.